# can i change tailwind css background color using map?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

```
     {sliderItems.map((item) => (
          <div className={`Slide w-screen h-screen flex items-center bg-[${item.bg}]`}>
```

I want to change the background color using map function.

but, never change the background color.

is it impossible?

[image]

Comment: What you're doing isn't possible, but it should be possible in other ways (making sliderItems part of state so they re-render on change, for example).

Comment: import { sliderItems } from "../pages/data";

 const [sliderItemss, setSliderItemss] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => setSliderItemss(sliderItems), []);

  console.log("sliderItems > ", sliderItems);

  {sliderItemss.map((item) => (
          <div
            className={`Slide w-screen h-screen flex items-center bg-[${item.bg}]`}
          >

same result .. ㅠㅠ

Comment: You cannot dynamically generate the classes, since they need to be added to the CSS file when Tailwind compiles (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71063619). You might consider storing the full class (e.g. `bg-[#fcf1ed]`) instead of just the color and then adding that to your `className` when you map over the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve that by defining the style already

like this:

```
const getRandomColor = () => {
    const colors = [
      'bg-red-400',
      'bg-yellow-400',
      'bg-green-400',
      'bg-blue-400',
      'bg-indigo-400',
      'bg-purple-400',
      'bg-pink-400',
    ];
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It doesn't work. For such situations in React.js or Next.js, I use the `style` attribute. here is my way of solving it:

```
{sliderItems.map((item) => (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor:item.bg}} className="Slide w-screen h-screen flex items-center">
    
    </div>
))}
```

this works for me.