# How to use dynamic class of tailwindcss like this in project of vue3 and vite?

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css, vite, tailwind-in-js

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "TestTailwind",
};
</script>
<script setup></script>

<template>
  <div class="">
    <div v-for="i in 20" :key="i" :class="[`m-${i}`]">m-{{ i }}</div>
    <div v-for="i in 20" :key="i" :class="[`p-${i}`]">p-{{ i }}</div>

  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>
```

I try to use dynamic class , but tailwind not give me the class right.

[image]

Expect:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React and Tailwind CSS: dynamically generated classes are not being applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71063619/react-and-tailwind-css-dynamically-generated-classes-are-not-being-applied)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of tailwind tree shaking. You need to add the classes you want to generate dynamically to the safelist in your `tailwind.config` file because tailwind can't detect used classes with this dinamic syntax.

Here is the code:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
  ],
  safelist: [
    'p-1',
    'p-2',
    'p-3',
    // ...
  ],
  // ...
}
```

You can read the docs [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes)