# Why isn't col-span spanning the full table width

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

This is my table code, using React and Tailwind CSS. There is one peculiarity: when col-span turns 8, it works as expected. But when it turns 12, it breaks.

I want the table to expand to 12 cols, but it only expands to 10. If I use 11 or 12 it goes to 1, no matter what I used for colspan.

```js
<div className={`flex flex-col lg:col-span-${order.smopen ? 8 : 12}`}>
  <div className="overflow-x-auto">
    <div className="align-middle inline-block min-w-full">
      <div className="shadow overflow-hidden border-b border-gray-200">
        <table
          className={`min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200 lg:col-span-${
            order.smopen ? 8 : 12
          }`}
        >
          <thead
            className={`min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200 lg:col-span-${
              order.smopen ? 8 : 12
            }`}
          >
            <tr>
              <th
                scope="col"
                className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider"
              >
                Тема
              </th>
              <th
                scope="col"
                className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider"
              >
                Дедлайн
              </th>
              <th
                scope="col"
                className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider"
              >
                Статус
              </th>
              <th
                scope="col"
                className="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider"
              >
                Сумма
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody
            className={`min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200 lg:col-span-${
              order.smopen ? 8 : 12
            }`}
          >
            {orders.map((order, orderIdx) => (
              <tr
                onClick={() =>
                  orderDispatch({
                    type: "selected",
                    payload: {
                      smopen: true,
                      title: order.title,
                      dateDeadline: new Date(order.dateDeadline).toLocaleString(
                        "ru-RU",
                        {
                          year: "numeric",
                          month: "long",
                          day: "numeric",
                        }
                      ),
                      status: order.status,
                      sum: order.sum,
                    },
                  })
                }
                key={order.id}
                className={
                  orderIdx % 2 === 0
                    ? "bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 cursor-pointer transition-all ease-in-out"
                    : "transition-all ease-in-out cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-100"
                }
              >
                <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                  {order.title}
                </td>
                <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
                  {new Date(order.dateDeadline).toLocaleString("ru-RU", {
                    year: "numeric",
                    month: "long",
                    day: "numeric",
                  })}
                </td>
                <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
                  {orderTypeSwitch(order.status)}
                </td>
                <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
                  {order.sum} ₽
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>;
```

How can I fix this to have my table span the whole 12 columns?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React and Tailwind CSS: dynamically generated classes are not being applied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71068925/287476)