# The transition property in Tailwind CSS is not working in my React element

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

It's my first time using Tailwind CSS and I have an element that needs to make a smooth transition between opacity 1 and 0. In this line of code, I´m updating the opacity with a useState hook (which is working fine) but there´s no transition, it just appears and dissappears. Can anybody see anything wrong with this?

```
<div id="cart" className={`relative opacity-${showCart ? "100" : "0"} transition-opacity duration-500`}>
```

Comment: you didn't post your code to your question as you said `In this line of code, I´m updating the opacity`

Comment: The code was there, but it was unescaped HTML (well, JSX) so it did not display in the question. Fixed now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React and Tailwind CSS: dynamically generated classes are not being applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71063619/react-and-tailwind-css-dynamically-generated-classes-are-not-being-applied)

Comment: If you want to do like that, you need to code `className={`relative ${showCart ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-0"},,,,`. Or use styled jsx.