# Update classes in react/tailwind css based on state with arbitrary values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, tailwind-css

I have a functional component called distance filter where I have a range input. In between the minimum and maximum widgets I want the background to be a different color as seen in the image below.
[image]

Here is my component:

```
export const DistanceFilter = () => {
  const [minimum, setMinimum] = useState(0)
  const [maximum, setMaximum] = useState(10)


  const handleMinChange = (e: any) => {
    setMinimum((prevState) => e.target.value)
  }

  const handleMaxChange = (e: any) => {
    setMaximum((prevState) => e.target.value)
  }


  
  return (
    <div className="w-full">
      <header>
        <h3>Price Range</h3>
      </header>
      <div className="w-full flex justify-between my-6">
        <div className="flex w-1/3 h-[45px] items-center gap-2 flex-grow">
          <span className="">Min</span>
          <input type="number" className="w-full text-center border rounded-md border-primary-mid" value={minimum} id="minimum" onChange={(e) => handleMinChange(e)}/>
        </div>
        <div className="flex items-center text-center justify-center px-3"><p>-</p></div>
        <div className="flex w-1/3 items-center gap-2 flex-grow">
          <span>Max</span>
          <input type="number" className="text-center w-full border rounded-md border-primary-mid" value={maximum} onChange={(e) => handleMaxChange(e)}/>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
      <div className="slider">
        <div className={`progress left-[${minimum / 50 * 100}%] right-[${100 - (maximum / 50 * 100)}%]`}></div>
      </div>
      <div className="range-input">
        <input type="range" className="range-min" min="0" max="50" value={minimum} step="1" onChange={(e) => handleMinChange(e)}/>
        <input type="range" className="range-max" min="0" max="50" value={maximum} step="1" onChange={(e) => handleMaxChange(e)}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When the DOM renders if I inspect the page the arbitrary values are in fact updating:

```
(these values update correctly in inspect)
<div className={`progress left-[${minimum / 50 * 100}%] right-[${100 - (maximum / 50 * 100)}%]`}></div>
```

However, when the dom is rendered the correct classes are not being displayed.
[image]

There is some rule in react that this is violating and I am not sure what it is or what the proper way to do something like this would be.

I tried using setAttribute in my handleMinChange and handleMaxChange functions like so:

```
const handleMinChange = (e: any) => {
  setMinimum((prevState) => e.target.value)
  e.target.setAttribute("left", `progress left-[${minimum / 50 * 100}%]`)
  }
```

This didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React and Tailwind CSS: dynamically generated classes are not being applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71063619/react-and-tailwind-css-dynamically-generated-classes-are-not-being-applied)

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

Consider applying the `left` and `right` properties in the `style` attribute like:

```
<div
  className="…"
  style={{
    left: `${minimum / 50 * 100}%`,
    right: `${100 - (maximum / 50 * 100)}%`
  }}
>
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the response this worked like magic.

Comment: Is this the recommended way to go when updating classes dynamically though?

Comment: Yes, I'd say so. For wide gamut of possible values, there is no other way. For a narrower set, you would have to `safelist` all the possible classes which then I would say is harder to maintain since the `safelist` list is now separated from your template code and also you may be generating extra CSS rules that you may never actually use.